# The Eclipse plugin cannot communicate with the GlassFish server

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I need use Glassfish in a project we're currently working on in Eclipse IDE.
My problem is after installing Glassfish Tools in Eclipse I manage to correctly create a new glassfish server en SERVERS tab but when I try to start it the following error message pop up:

> The Eclipse plugin cannot communicate with the GlassFish server....
>   The Eclipse plugin cannot communicate with the GlassFish server. A
>   GlassFish Enterprise Server may be running on the same admin or HTTP
>   port, but with a different root installation.Please also check for
>   antivirus software, firewall configuration, or VPN setup which might
>   block some ports.

Actually the problem looks more complex since not only I'm not able to start server but I cannot execute any action on server. Neither deploying, nor clean or whaterever else do work resulting in popping up the above message.

In the internet developers communities I only find clues about CREDENTIAL ERROR but this is not the case.
Looking in the Glassfish log folder there is no trace of any access attempt.
Everythings points at Eclipse plug-in neither be able to communicate with glassfish by any circumstance.

This issue occours either with  Glassfish 3.1 (using jdk1.7) and 4.1 (using jdk1.8) and in Eclipse Luna and Mars.

I already tried to create, delete and manage glassfish domains (as suggested in other questions here at StackOverflow) to get over potential "credential-related" issues but no result.

Tried to uninstall and reinstall Glassfish Tools from Eclipse too but still no way.

Both Glasshfish 3.1 an 4.1 start flawlessly manually and NetBeans manage to start them without any problem but, as said, I need to work with eclipse so switching to NetBeans is not the solution (and, please, don't suggest me a manual deploy and server start).

As a last attempt, since I work in Windows, in a console window I tried this:

```
netstat -a -b
```

to verify no other service is "taking" port 8080 (although it doesn't seem to be a port problem but a "plug-in communication" one) but it resulted free.

I'm into this mess by days. 
Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55218770/6801721). It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly the same problem. When I set "preserve sessions across redeployment" in the Eclipse properties dialog for GlassFish, tab "GlassFish", to false (true being the default), everything worked out fine.

Comment: Thank you. Tried it. Unfortunateley didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I just set the proxy configuration in Eclipse menu Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections (changing the Active Provider value from "Native" to "Manual" and inserting all the needed values for HTTP and HTTPS rows) and added "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" to the section "Proxy bypass".

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Generally, the programs that get dynamicly port numbers causes this. Etc: skype, teamviewer.

For me, I solved the problem with starting eclipse before them.

Maybe this works for you too.

Comment: Thank you for your help. unfortunately this is not my case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by removing the glassfish server from Eclipse, and adding it again.

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed in my own case was that other applications where using port number 4848, so I had to stop all use of port 4848 and restart the domain again ( restart glassfish server )